# How to access root directory in html?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, relative-path, absolute-path

I am just beginning HTML and I wanted to know how to use root directory in HTML?

I have a `css` and `js` folder in the root directory and I linked it(using relative URL) for the index.html in that directory. But now I have a subdirectory called `foo` along with the `css` and `js` sub-directory's. Now in the foo folder I cannot use relative URL because the `css` folder is not in that directory.

Do I have to use absolute URL, or is there a way to use `/code_for_main_dir/css`

Comment: use ./css   relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path starting with / means root directory.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mytheme.css">
```

More info:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1):

As @thesilkworm said,

using `..`goes one directory up.

But, using `/` goes to the root of that web.

so, `/css` instead of `css`